# Why is a property not recognized when looping through a list?

Tags: angular, typescript

## The Setup

I have a class called `myClass`:

```
export class myClass
{
    name: string;
    age: number;
    city: string;
}
```

and I have another class called `people`:

```
export class people
{
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
```

Within my `component.ts` I have declared `listMyClass : myClass[];` which is populated from `ngOnInit()` using data from an API.

## The Goal

I want to create a method in `component.ts` which loops through the `listMyClass` and if the city matches london it gets added to a list of the `people` class.

I thought I would be able to write something (the method I want to create) outside of `ngOnInit()` along the lines of:

```
getLondonPeople(){     
    for (let item in listMyClass) {
        if (item.city == "london") {
            //do something
        }
    }

    return listPeople;
}
```

## The Problem

I get an error on `item.city` stating the following:

> Property 'city' does not exist on type 'string'.

How to solve this?

Comment: Please provide more code. For me your problem is not fully clear

Comment: A list of people can't be of type people. It must an **array** of people. And you must of course **create** the array. Then you need to learn which methods exist on arrays. The method you're looking for is push(), not add(). And finally you need to **return** the array from the method.

Comment: Angular 7/Typescript is not a question.

Comment: Note that declaring a variable is done with `let variable` or `const variable`. Not just `variable`. This is all pretty basic TypeScript/JavaScript syntax. You should learn a good book about it and practice with simple stuff before trying to use Angular.

Comment: Use `enum` and export as interface instead of class

Comment: edited the question as I made some dumb mistakes as I was in a rush

Comment: Try `for (let item of listMyClass)` with `of` instead of `in`.

Answer (score 1):

## Cause

You get this error because with `for-in` you do not actually iterate over the things you are interested in. As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Difference_between_for...of_and_for...in):

> Both `for...in` and `for...of` statements iterate over something. The main difference between them is in what they iterate over.
>
> The `for...in` statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in an arbitrary order.
>
> The `for...of` statement iterates over values that the iterable object defines to be iterated over.

## Solution

Considering the cause, I would suggest you to use `for-of` instead of `for-in` like this:

```
for (let item of listMyClass) ...
```

**Even better**, in order to get the items you need use `filter` instead of `for-loop`, i.e

```
this.listMyClass.filter(item => item.city === 'London')
```

## Example

Here is a simple example I have prepared for you on Stackblitz in order to demonstrate the proposed solutions:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/unrecognized-property